# Browse current directory and find files starting with "lib" and exclude subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, linux-mint

I want to search files in the current directory starting with "lib". I want to eliminate sub directories.

I am trying following command, but it is not giving any files. Anything wrong in the following command?

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "lib*.*" -type "f"
```

Comment: Remember to forget the DOS Think that `*.*` equals `*`.  You might want to add to your question why you think that the current directory actually has filenames beginning `lib` and with a dot in, in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment, in Unix, `*.*` means the file name must contain a period. 
If your file names don’t contain periods, use `-name "lib*"`; e.g.,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "lib*" -printf '%f\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me, as long as I am actually in the directory:

```
$ cd /lib
$ find -maxdepth 1 -name "lib*.*" -type "f"
./libthread_db-1.0.so
./libfreebl3.so
./libnsl-2.12.so
./libnss_compat-2.12.so
./libcidn-2.12.so
./libdl-2.12.so
./libnss_hesiod-2.12.so
./libresolv-2.12.so
./libz.so.1.2.3
./libm-2.12.so
./libanl-2.12.so
./libpthread-2.12.so
./libutil-2.12.so
./libnss_dns-2.12.so
./libnss_files-2.12.so
./libcrypt-2.12.so
./libBrokenLocale-2.12.so
./libfreebl3.chk
./libnss_nisplus-2.12.so
./libSegFault.so
./libc-2.12.so
./librt-2.12.so
./libnss_nis-2.12.so
```

I am guessing you issued your command from another directory. In any case it is more usual to specify the directory you want to use as a starting point, eg:

```
find /lib -maxdepth 1 -name "lib*.*" -type "f"
```

Also as others have noted in the comments, `*.*` means the filename must contain a '.' (as it happens if searching in a directory containing libraries then most likely they will all contain a dot).